# Custom wordpress function to display related posts based on multiple tags

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm building a wordpress site and want to show related posts based on tags when viewing a single post. Currently I'm using the below function to do this and it works.

My issue is that I want to prioritise related posts that have the most tags in common. Usually I have 3-5 tags for each posts so I want to display posts with 3 tags in common before 1 tag for example. I've tried some different code snippets that should be able to do this but I haven't managed to get it to work so far.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

```
function smak_related_posts() {
  global $post;
  $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
  if($tags) {
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
      $tag_arr .= $tag->slug . ',';
    }
    $args = array(
      'tag' => $tag_arr,
      'numberposts' => 4,
      'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
      'post_type' => array('post', 'projects'),
    );
    $related_posts = get_posts( $args );
    if($related_posts) {
      echo '<footer class="entry-footer">';
        echo '<h3>Se også...</h3>';
        echo '<div id="masonry-loop">';
          get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'masonry_sizer' );
          foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
                  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'masonry' );
          endforeach; }
          }
        echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```